# Cypress secure to use with production data

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use cypress for running some monitoring tests on production.I am also using snapshot match plugin to compare screenshots.
I just want to know is this safe to do ?
I am not using any dashboard services from cypress -just running tests on our local machines-will cypress sent any info outside our network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress doesn't send anything to Cypress's servers unless you specifically configure it to - it's safe.

The only other thing is, by default, Cypress will send crash reports (when Cypress itself crashes) to be analyzed. You can turn this off by [following the instructions here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Opt-out-of-sending-exception-data-to-Cypress).